# CRTP -- accessing incomplete type members

Tags: c++, c++11, crtp, incomplete-type

Related questions: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006614/c-static-polymorphism-crtp-and-using-typedefs-from-derived-classes), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098647/why-cant-my-curiously-recurring-template-pattern-crtp-refer-to-the-derived-cl)

After trying to understand CRTP for several days it seems that now I understand even less than before:)

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class IMPL>
class Interace
{
public:
    typedef typename IMPL::TYPE TYPE;  // ERROR: "...invalid use of incomplete type..."
    void foo() { IMPL::impl(); }       // then why does this work?
};

class Implementation : public Interface<Implementation>
{
public:
   typedef int TYPE;
   static void impl() { std::cout << "impl() " << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    Implementation obj;
    obj.foo();
}
```

The questions are:

1. Why I can call function from `IMPL::` (line 8) but cannot access type fileds (line 7)? In related question it is said that `IMPL` is an incomplete type at this point. But why then line 8 is correct?
2. What it the order of type declaration/definition? As I see it:

a. `Interface` template -- OK. Doesn't bring any problems until instantiating

b. line 11 -- after `class Implementation` -- `Implementation` type declared but not defined.

c. line 11 -- after `Interface<Implementation>` -- template instantiation. At this point `Implementation` is already known (but not defined!) due to step (b). Compiler "injects" code with `IMPL` replaced with `Implementation`. Here, to my point of view, neither line 7, neither line 8 are not legal because at this point, compiler doesn't know that `Implementation` has these members. How does it knows than?

Or maybe Instantiation really goes at line 21? But in that case why line 07 doesn't work?

More I think about it, less understanding of C++ type fundamentals I have. Any clarification is appreciated.

Comment: @273K line numbers were intentional -- there are a few references to specific lines (not code logical blocks -- specifc lines) in the question body. Your edit makes it less readable

Comment: Sorry, I missed the references in the text and removed the line numbers since they prevent from easy copy-compile. I can mark the referenced lines in code comments. FYI I used your question for closing a new similar question as a duplicate of your question.

Comment: No worries, I saw the copy-paste friendliness intention) That would be a great compromise, thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When a class template is instantiated, its members other than non-virtual member functions are instantiated together with it. Non-virtual member functions, however, are only instantiated when odr-used (basically, called or have their address taken).

When the compiler encounters `class Implementation : public Interface<Implementation>`, it needs to instantiate `Interface<Implementation>`. At this point, `Implementation` is still an incomplete type, its `TYPE` member has not yet been seen. On the other hand, `Interface<Implementation>::foo` is only instantiated later, when it's called in `main`. At that point, `Implementation` is a complete type.

Comment: Pass an additional parameter to `Interface`, as in `Implementation : public Interface<Implementation, int>`. Have `Interface` typedef `TYPE` from that parameter, then `Implementation` wouldn't need to.